# Cannot login to Xbox Live on Lumia 535

Tags: 8.1, xbox-live, nokia-lumia-535

I have been trying for a couple of days to login to Xbox Live on a Lumia 535 but can't. Searching on Google did not help much except I found some other people who have the same problem but no solution.

[image]

Has anybody overcome this problem?

Comment: Do other services (like the store) work as expected? Have you set date and time correctly?

Comment: I had this problem a couple of days ago. I don't remember if I did something to solve but it's now solved. Do games with Xbox Live work? Like `Make it rain` or `Tiny Troopers`?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, everything else is working just fine.

Comment: @VitorCanova Have not installed those games.

Comment: @JubayerArefin Can you try start a Xbox Live game?

Comment: I will try that

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Settings > date+time then change your Time zone format to nearest location where you are.

That's what I did and it works! :)